# Change the URL to access my Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

I have a servlet which is basically a `hello world` kind of...

The class is:

```
package net.jgp.baseapp.validation.tomcat;
[...]
@WebServlet(name = "tv", description = "...", urlPatterns = {"/TomcatValidator", "/" })
    public class TomcatValidator extends HttpServlet {
    [...]
    }
}
```

It works great when I launch it through:

```
http://localhost:8081/net.jgp.baseapp.validation.tomcat/tv
http://localhost:8081/net.jgp.baseapp.validation.tomcat/qwe?test=89
```

etc.

However, can I change the `net.jgp.baseapp.validation.tomcat` to:

1. Nothing, basically it should run like `http://localhost:8081`?
2. A simpler URL `http://localhost:8081/toto`?

So far, my web.xml is really empty (the default from Eclipse generation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I've looked at a lot of things, and I must admit I am getting crazy :)...

Thanks!

PS: I know that:

```
@WebServlet(name = "tv", description = "...", urlPatterns = {"/TomcatValidator", "/" })
```

is somehow equal to:

```
@WebServlet(name = "tv", description = "...", urlPatterns = {"/" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things here.

If you want your servlet to serve the root URL, you have to do two things

1 - you have to set your webapp context to root, like this

[image]

2 - then you have to set your servlet context to root too

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().write("OK");
        response.getWriter().flush();
    }

}
```

that's because the URL your servlet serve is like this

```
http://yourserver:port/yourapp/yourservlet
```

where yourapp is defined by #1

and yourservlet is defined by #2

like this

[image]

Comment: Great! How do you get the first UI you kindly uploaded. I use eclipse (too?). or could you share your web.xml? tx!

Comment: go to the "servers" tab, select your server, double-click, and then go to the "modules" tab. The web.xml is the default generated by eclipse, like yours

Comment: perfect! thanks... however, where is this information saved? i did not see it in the web.xml? is it only available at the appserver level (it would make sense).

Comment: Yes, it is on container config